# Why do bluebirdjs promises work with await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Sorry in advance if somebody is wounded by my silly question, but anyway:

I always thought that `await` can work properly only with **native Promises**. But today I encountered that **bluebirdjs** promises are also properly handled by `await`.

My questions are:

1) How and why does `await` really work with **non-native Promises**?

2) How can I implement my own **Promise object** which will work correctly with `await`?

```
const BluebirdPromise = require('bluebird');

function sleep(mls) {
  return new BluebirdPromise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, mls));
}

async function test() {
  await sleep(5000); // waits 5000 mls
  console.log('done'); // printed after 5000 mls
}

test();
```

Comment: I hope the duplicate question (and the posts linked from there) should answer all your questions. If not, please comment.

Comment: tl;dr *(I may be wrong here but this is what I understant)*
ES6 can async-await any Promise. (A function that has resolve-reject callback.)